# Are there any C# samples for Multi-Itinerary Route Optimization using the Bing Maps REST API?

Tags: c#, bing-maps

The BingMapsRESTToolkit has some great samples for much of the functionality provided by the Bing Maps API. But there isn't a sample for Multi-Itinerary Route Optimization (MIO), and I have been unable to find anything on the web.

I can see the Microsoft Documentation which provides sample JSON for MIO. But I would like to find a C# sample that wraps the creation of such JSON and then utilizes the response to push the routes onto a BingMapsControl, such as the rest of the BingMapsRESTToolkit does.

MS MIO Documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/articles/create-an-optimized-itinerary

Comment: Which BIng Maps control are you planning on using? Web SDK, WPF SDK, UWP SDK, Unity SDK? Note that the WPF SDK is very limited in features and not actively maintained (as noted in docs), and it is recommended to use the UWP SDK via a XAML island in WPF apps now.

Comment: Hello, the plan was to use WPF and Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF. But that can easily change to UWP like you say. The BingMapsRESTToolkit is WPF, but it is also old and not maintained.
Are there MIO examples in UWP? I dont see any upon first inspection.

Comment: The BingMapsRESTToolkit is .NET core, it works in UWP as well, but UWP examples aren't added to the solution as it requires developers to install a lot of stuff to their dev environment. It is old, but heavily used. I'll see if I can add in the MIO service to it and put together a sample. There isn't any UWP samples of MIO that I know of. I'll put a sample in WPF in the BingMapsToolkit.

Comment: That would be amazing, thank you! There is also a .NET Standard side-by-side version. But either version is fine and would help alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a pull request to the Bing Maps REST Toolkit that adds support for MOI and includes a pretty in depth sample. Not sure if or when the NuGet will be updated, but you can download the source code and reference the project into your solution locally to get access to all this. Here is a link to the code sample: https://github.com/microsoft/BingMapsRESTToolkit/tree/master/Samples/WPF/MultiRouteOptimizationSample

Comment: Thank you very much for this example, it will help alot!